# Accessing Matlab structure array without field names

Tags: matlab

I have a structure with two unnamed fields that I need to access individually as vectors. The matlab help page only has examples with field names.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-structure-array.html

How do I retrieve an unnamed field?

Edit

For example, my data looks like this:

```
0.5000  0.1338
0.4999  0.1445
0.4998  0.0716
```

and not like:

```
x       y
0.5000  0.1338
0.4999  0.1445
0.4998  0.0716
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by an unnamed field in a structure. All fields by definition require a name. Can you include sample data in your question?

Comment: Are you certain you're dealing with a *structure*, and not a `table` or other data type? You can check the data type with `class(s)`, where `s` is the variable holding your data.

Comment: My data is apparently a table inside a structure. I used the term field interchangeably with column when I meant the latter. I see where that was inappropriate particularly given the context of a matlab structure. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the field names *a priori*, you can use [`fieldnames`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html) to get them, then access them using the returned values:

```
names = fieldnames(s);
vec1 = s.(names{1});
vec2 = s.(names{2});
```

Alternatively, you can ignore them altogether and just place the structure field contents in a cell array using [`struct2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html):

```
vecs = struct2cell(s);
vec1 = vecs{1};
vec2 = vecs{2};
```